# Change image depending on the value of XML property

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, xml

In below snippet, I want to be able to change the image depending on the value of the External XML file using json, and ajax. For Example, if the value of BASIC is 1:00, the image would be 1.png, and if it's 12:00, the image would change to 2.gif. I tried searching in google for quiet some time but haven't had any luck. Though I believe I can use GET method to import the value of XML file, but not really sure of how can I go about passing the value of the XML into javascript object and execute a function from there.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

  <head>
</head>

<img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/dbz-png-imagenes-que-les-volaran-la-mente-2-imagenes-900.png" style="width: 400px; height: 500px;">
  

</body>

</html>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
    <Property Name="Label1" Type="System.String">BASIC</Property>
    <Property Name="Label2" Type="System.String">1:00</Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

Would appreciate any kind of idea or snippet to achieve my goal. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

#### Even though I do JSON, I'm Going to try and answer.

Get your XML data with ajax.
then write a function to be called in the onreadystatechange.
the function calling should look like this: `myFunction(this);`
write your function like this:

```
function myFunction(stuff)
{
 var myStuff = stuff.responseXML;
 var s = myStuff.getElementsByTagName("Object");
 //your if statement here

}
```

use `s[0].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue` to get the data.